# I find the table but can't get the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have the piece of html below. The table is used for JQgrid.

```
<section id="section_students">
<table id="grid_students"></table>
<a class="btn" href="#">Click</a>
</section>
```

And I'm intending to use JQuery to find out the value of the table if a button under the same section is clicked.

```
$("section a.btn").click(function(){
var curGrid = $(this).parent().find('table').get(0);
alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
});
```

This alert will return 'undefined' and I can't understand why.
What am  I missing?

EDIT: Looks like JQGrid changes the ID of the table, which is weird. I'll be researching this, meanwhile, if anyone knows how to prevent this behavior, please let me know.

Comment: Which browser are you using and which version of jQuery? Your code seems OK and I dont think there are any issues.

Comment: It's working correct. http://jsfiddle.net/E2KRG/. I think, the problem related to version of jQuery.

Comment: Maybe JQGrid messes up the id? Testing that...

Comment: Yes! JQGrid changes the ID apparently.

Comment: Your code is working please check http://jsfiddle.net/n4Dy9/

Comment: I edited the post regarding the JQGrid behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqGrid converts the original `<table>` (`<table id="grid_students"></table>` in your example) in complex structure of tabeles and dives. The most simple modification of your original code could be

```
$("section a.btn").click(function(){
    var curGrid = $(this).parent().find('table.ui-jqgrid-btable').get(0);
    alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
});
```

(I use the fact that jqGrid set `ui-jqgrid-btable` class on the original `<table>`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#section_students").find("a.btn").click(function(){
var curGrid = $(this).parent().find('table').get(0);
alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Sorry. Pressed `Enter` by accident before I was done. What I meant was:
Even better, try
`$("#section_students").on("click", "a.btn", function(){
var curGrid = $(this).siblings('table').get(0);
alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
});`
These both shouldn't really change the outcome, though, maybe make it faster."

Answer (score 0):

It works well, did you put the javascript code into jquery ready().

```
$(function(){
    $("section a.btn").click(function(){
    var curGrid = $(this).parent().find('table').get(0);
    alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your code in $(document).ready(function(){     ......    });

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("section a.btn").click(function(){
    var curGrid = $(this).parent().find('table').get(0);
    alert($(curGrid).attr("id"));
    });
});
```